# Talend tRunJob CHILD_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE is empty

Tags: talend

I'm trying to catch the error message raised inside a tRunJob subjob. The job tree is minimal:

```
Main_Job -- execute a subjob and catch the output
> Sub_Job -- do some stuff and can raise an error.
```

For a test I try to raise an error but the stack trace is empty.

The jobs are made this way:

1. The `Sub_Job` contains a `tDie` to raise the error;
2. I need to get the error message in the `Main_Job`, possibly the stack trace, so after the `tRunJob` I handle the error with a `tJava`;

The tJava use `globalMap` to get the stack trace, as following:

```
System.out.println(
"myLog --->> "+ ((String)globalMap.get("tRunJob_1_ERROR_MESSAGE")));

System.out.println(
"myLog --->> "+ (String)globalMap.get("tRunJob_1_CHILD_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE")));
```

The output on console is flat: generic error message and no stack:

```
myLog --->> Child job running failed.

myLog --->> 
[statistics] disconnected
```

I want `CHILD_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE` value, but for a tRunJob seems to be empty. Is there any option I don't see? Have I to load manually the stack trace, from inside `Sub_Job`? How?

Below are the simple `Main_Job` and `Sub_Job`:

[image: Main_Job]

[image: Sub_Job]

Thanks

Comment: In your real job, is the error raised by a tDie ? if so, the tDie doesn't have a stack trace, that's why it's empty.
If your error is an exception, you should get a stack trace.  
What do you get when you run the subjob directly (as opposed to running it from within the parent job) ?

Comment: Thanks! The error is raised by a SQL Server Stored procedure. In the first attemp I didn't get stack strace nethier by that, but I used only the tDie for the further tests. I will check soon with a more complete test.

Comment: I've tested with an sp. I got the stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: I have a following question: in my subjobs I use `tDie` when I have to  raise an error. In these cases, how can I insert some text in the Stack Trace? If I can't, I have to drop `tDie` and raise exceptions via `tJava`

Comment: tDie doesn't allow you to define a stack trace, you can throw an exception in a tJava `throw new Exception("some error")`

Comment: Is there any way, in all Talend, to push some message in the Stack Trace of the current job? I mean, not concerning `tDie`. It can be useful on any situation.

Comment: The stack trace is that of java, you can't change it. You can use the error message for that.

Comment: Ok. How can I change the value of the error message? When I use a `tDie`, the error message is always the same:  `(String)globalMap.get("tRunJob_1_ERROR_MESSAGE") = "Child job running failed"` (it doesn’t matter which message I set in the `tDie` component). Is there a way to inflate the text of the error message?